# Azure B2C Update Custom User Attribute Programmatically

Tags: updates, azure-ad-b2c

In my B2C tenant I've added a new Custom User Attribute: `org`

I've added `org` as a Claim so that when the user logs in I can see the custom Claim.

I now want to in code update this value. I've tried sending a `PATCH` request to the appropriate endpoint:

https://graph.windows.net/myb2c.onmicrosoft.com/users/userObjectId?api-version=1.6

But am receiving the following error:

> One or more property values specified are invalid.

Here is the JSON I am sending:

```
{ "extension_org": "1234" }
```

Is there another way I need to update this value?

Screenshots for reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just tried to programmatically add a custom extension attribute using the Azure AD Graph API but it isn't showing up in the list of user attributes. Can you tell me how you did that? I see it when I use the graph to pull back all extension attributes from the b2c_extensions_app app and I can set it via a user update graph call but this blade doesn't show it.

Comment: I didn't programatically add the Attribute. I just clicked on 'User attributes' on my B2C and manually added 'org'

Comment: Additionally I created a custom extension attribute as well via the Graph, but agreed I don't know how that then shows up as a Claim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the graph API to get the extension attributes for the B2C extension app, you'll see the application ID inserted into the name. So, it will be `extension_{appId}_org` as the extension name.

To find the application ID, within your B2C directory, go to the Azure Active Directory blade, click on App Registrations, then View All Applications. You'll see a `b2c_extension_app`. Click on that and it's application ID will be displayed.

If you prefer using the AAD Graph API, you can use the applications endpoint with a filter to get the application ID: ...`/applications?api-version=1.6&$filter=startswith(displayName, 'b2c-extensions-app')`. That will return JSON like so:

```
{
"odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application",
"value": [{
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application",
        "objectType": "Application",
        "objectId": "319f43e4-6b2e-4de8-abdb-549ca5c0626",
        "deletionTimestamp": null,
        "acceptMappedClaims": null,
        "addIns": [],
        "appId": "8588c037-999f-4d05-8cc0-8e2e5f9de30",
        "appRoles": [],
        "availableToOtherTenants": false,
        "displayName": "b2c-extensions-app. Do not modify. Used by AADB2C for storing user data.",
        "errorUrl": null,
        "groupMembershipClaims": null,
        "homepage": "https://extensions.cpim.windows.net",
        "identifierUris": ["https://extensions.cpim.windows.net"],
        .
        .
        .
    }
]
}
```

The appId is the value you want for `extension_{appId}_org`

Comment: Yes. But extensions are related an application - and bound to a user. If you remove the application, the extension data is removed as well. That's why the b2c-extensions-app says not to remove or modify it.

Comment: So is this answering my question? Not sure I follow

Comment: My first comment on this answer answers your first comment. But, here is a link to read up on it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-create-custom-attributes-profile-edit-custom

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't talk about how to programatically update the extension attribute in code

Comment: I figured it out! I didn't realize the pre registered app would work for my needs. One thing to be aware of is if you selected the extension attribute as a claim, you won't see it show up in your list of claims until you actually update the extension with a value.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working like this:

```cs
// Retrieving the user by email
var user = B2CService.GetUser(email);

// Crafting the extension attribute name
var extensionAttribute = $"extension_REPLACEWITHYOURB2CEXTENSIONSAPPID_AttributeName";

// Craft the URL
var url = B2CService.BuildUrl($"/users/{user.ObjectId}");

var jsonUpdate = new JObject
{
    { extensionAttribute, "ValueHere" }
};

// Patching the extension attribute value...
await B2CService.SendGraphRequest(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), url, jsonUpdate.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to this information, make sure to remove the dashes in the ApplicationID.  See the Microsoft [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api).

```
"extension_831374b3bd5041bfaa54263ec9e050fc_org": "212342"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me.

```
PATCH 
"/users/{objectId}/extension_{applicationId}_org"

{ "value": "1234" }
```

don't patch the whole user, just the property.